# Wrapping multiple identically named elements into a new element using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to reformat some XML using XSLT. A snippet of my input looks like this:

```
<toggles>
  <toggle toggleDisplayName="Charges">
    <anotherElement attribute="value" />
    <gridColumn sourceField.name="FIELD1" />
    <gridColumn sourceField.name="FIELD2" />
    <gridColumn sourceField.name="FIELD3" />
  </toggle>
</toggles>
```

I want to wrap all 'gridColumn' elements into a single 'grid' element like so:

```
<toggles>
  <toggle toggleDisplayName="Charges">
    <anotherElement attribute="value" />
    <grid>
      <gridColumn sourceField.name="FIELD1" />
      <gridColumn sourceField.name="FIELD2" />
      <gridColumn sourceField.name="FIELD3" />
    </grid>
  </toggle>
</toggles>
```

My current XSLT is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
     exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="toggle/gridColumn">
    <grid>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </grid>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Identity transform for remaining-->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Right now this sort of works, but I get each 'gridColumn' element in its own 'grid' element. Is there any easy way to modify this so that I can obtain the aforementioned results?

Note: edited to clarify input XML.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Create a template for `<toggle>` that wraps `<grid>` around its children.

Comment: Sorry the XML I have is quite long, so perhaps I cut out too much of it. There are also other elements under 'toggle' that are not 'gridColumns'. The method you propose would wrap all child elements of 'toggle' into the 'grid' element, which is not what I wanted to do.

Comment: Create a template for `<toggle>` that wraps `<grid>` around its `<gridColumn>` children, then, by specifying the latter in the contained `<xsl:apply-templates>`. Or clarify the requirement, if I'm still misunderstanding you.

Comment: "there are other elements under `toggle` that are not `gridColumns`" - are all the `gridColumn` elements adjacent?  If not, do you want to gather them _all_ together into one group or just group adjacent ones (so you end up with more than one `grid` in the output)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest variant I can think of, which works if all the `gridColumn` elements are adjacent (forming one contiguous block with no other intervening elements) in the original input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="toggle">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- apply templates to everything except the second and subsequent
           gridColumn child elements -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(self::gridColumn)]
                                      | gridColumn[1]" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- this template will be called for just the first gridColumn within
       a toggle... -->
  <xsl:template match="gridColumn">
    <grid>
      <!-- ... and will gather all its sibling gridColumn elements under the
           new grid element -->
      <xsl:copy-of select="../gridColumn" />
    </grid>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Identity transform for remaining-->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If the `gridColumn` elements are not all adjacent you'll find that they've all been gathered together into a single `<grid>` at the place where the *first* `gridColumn` appeared in the input XML.

Comment: Awesome! I tweaked it a bit because I had already done some by hand, so essentially I had to add a rule to copy existing 'grid' tags and children as-is. Otherwise yours works perfectly. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution. Please check if it fulfills all your requirements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <!-- Process toggle separately, because its childredn cannot simply be copied -->
  <xsl:template match="toggle">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="./@*" /> <!-- For some unknown reason I needed this -->
      <xsl:apply-templates />
      <grid>
        <xsl:for-each select="gridColumn">
          <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:for-each>
      </grid>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="gridColumn">
    <!-- Do nothing, because it is processed by for-each -->
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Identity transform for remaining-->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tweaked yours to work too, and I would upvote it but my reputation isn't high enough yet. Thank you for replying!